# I want not to consider blank cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to calculate my data using the Sum function, but some cells are empathy. I have used this function, but it does not work for me. I googled it, but I was unsuccessful to find the solution.

SUM(IF(A2<70,1),IF(B2<70,1),IF(C<70,1))

For example, in cells B and C I have some blank cells, but I want to ignore them.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: change the ifs to something like this: `IF(AND(A2<70,A2<>""),1)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `ISBLANK()` This will return a Boolean T/F

**Untested**
Alternatively Improved logic should work. I'm unsure of syntax but this should work.
`=SUM(IF(0>A2<70,1),IF(0>B2<70,1),IF(0>C3<70,1))`

`SUMIFS()` will also work as you can add multiple criteria.

Comment: And ISBLANK will return FALSE, if the cell is populated with a formula that returns `""`

Comment: @Scott You are correct, I believe your comment seems the most appropriate.